# Get two different delimiters from same string

Tags: java

How can I use split function in java using two delimiters in the same string
I want to get the words with commas and spaces separately

```
String I = "hello,hi hellow,bye"
```

I want to get the above string splited as

```
String var1 = hello,bye
String var2 = hi hellow
```

Any suggestion is very much valued.

Comment: You may want to add more/longer sample data to get the point across.

Comment: So in other words, you want to split this string by the comma delimiter (`,`) and then put all entries with a space in it into one group, and all other entries into the other group?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to first split them with one of the delimiters, then for each resulting substring split with the other delimiter.